# How to load Dialog or Popup before page load using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-popup, jquery-mobile-dialog

Is there any method to call/show Dialog or popup before page load using jquery Mobile?

I want to get some input before page load and according to that input next page will be loaded

Comment: I want to get some input before page load and according to that input next page will be loaded

Comment: the solution is on, http://stackoverflow.com/a/10285950/1722141

Comment: r u suggestin this is duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

To load a dialog or a popup before showing a page, you need to use `seTimeout`. if you call it without a delay, it will open and close at once.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#pageID', function() {
 setTimeout(function () {
  $('#popupID').popup('open');
 }, 100); // delay above zero
});
```

> **[Similar issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692186/jquery-mobile-dialog-on-page-load)**

Answer (score 1):

There's a very simple solution to your question, only thing you need to do is make your first page to be a dialog.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/dj3UP/1/

As you can see it in my example this is a pure HTML solution. First page **data-role** attribute was changed to **dialog**.

**HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="dialog" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <input type="text" value="" id="some-input"/>
            <a data-role="button" id="some-button" href="#second">Next page</a>
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div> 
    <div data-role="page" id="second">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                Second Page
            </h3>
            <a href="#index" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try Following:**

```
$.mobile.loading( 'show', {
    text: 'foo',
    textVisible: true,
    theme: 'z',
    html: ""
});
```

**Refere Link:**

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/loader.html